# How to make text boxes use the numbering for theorem environments?

Tags: tcolorbox, amsart

I would like to make text boxes, say for theorems, that render as numbered text boxes which respect the numbering of other environments (definitions, theorems, etc) in the amsart class template.

For example, if I use the predefined Definition environment in the amsart class to create Definition 1.3, I would like to then create a text box for a theorem right after that would render as Theorem 1.4.

The following works but for some reason the text that should go in the box partially appears in the small box surrounding the title of the box.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=theorem]{mytheo}{Theorem}{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=gray!20!white,%
    colframe=gray!80!black,
    size=small,
    boxrule=1pt,
    title=\textbf{Theorem},
    halign title=flush center,
    coltitle=black,
    breakable,
    drop shadow=black!50!white,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    minipage boxed title=2.5cm,
    boxed title style={%
        colback=white,
        size=fbox,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=2pt,
        underlay={%
            \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
            \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (interior.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3ex]interior.east);
                \filldraw [white, blur shadow={shadow opacity=60, shadow yshift=-.75ex}, rounded corners=2pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
                \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
                \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
            \end{scope}
        },
    },
    #1,
}
{th}
```

Comment: Welcome ... Please provide your code (what you tried sofar) as `MWE`, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem` has an optional *<shared counter>* argument to define theorem environment that share the counter of another one. See Section 3 of the manual [`amsthdoc.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf). AFAIK `\newtheorem` of `amsart` has the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing some tcolobox and tikz libraries.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins} % for attached boxed title to top left,  minipage boxed title, boxed title style, enhanced jigsaw, drop shadow,
\tcbuselibrary{theorems} % for the `\newtcbstheorem` macro
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % for the breakable option
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur} % for the 'blur shadow' option in the underlay

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=theorem]{mytheo}{Theorem}{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=gray!20!white,
    colframe=gray!80!black,
    size=small,
    boxrule=1pt,
    title=\textbf{Theorem},
    halign title=flush center,
    coltitle=black,
    breakable,
    drop shadow=black!50!white,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    minipage boxed title=2.5cm,
    boxed title style={%
        colback=white,
        size=fbox,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=2pt,
        underlay={%
            \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
            \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (interior.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3ex]interior.east);
                \filldraw [white, blur shadow={shadow opacity=60, shadow yshift=-.75ex}, rounded corners=2pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
                \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
                \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
            \end{scope}
        },
    },
    #1,
}
{th}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        this is a theorem
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{mytheo}{}{} % #1 = env name, #2 = Title, #3 = label 
    this is a boxed theorem
    \end{mytheo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are not sure which exact libraries you need for your colored boxes, it is recommended to use the `most` option of the tcolorbox package, i.e., write `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` instead of `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` it will load all commonly used libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not provided full `MWE`, I've used the class file `amsbook`, and the full `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{definition}
Test
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added it now.